# How do I force selection of a keyboard type in a Xamarin.Webkit.Webview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

We have a Xamarin app (Android) that at one stage opens up a web view (Webkit.Webview not Forms.Webview).  This directs the user to a page on a third party site which has been set up for us.

Firstly - on certain input fields the keyboard which shows up is the wrong one - we are expecting a dismissable keyboard (i.e. "Done" in the bottom corner, not a "Submit"). I know this can be changed but not sure what is the correct way to do this. Does it have to be the metadata/text inputs on the web page that is changed? If so - **what needs to be modified per text box entry on the html of the page?** Just the type? i.e:

```
<input type="email">
```

Secondly, rather than wait for the third party to fix the page, **is there a way we can force the webview to always open a certain keyboard type?**

We have an option of intercepting the keyboard key presses and trying to dismiss the keyboard on return press at the minute. But would prefer not to put a hack in that intercepts every key press.

Appreciate the help, not sure what the way forward is here.

Thanks

Comment: To your second question about forcing a keyboard type, it looks like [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65222/inputmethods-editorinfo-imeoptions-data-type-wrong-problem-when-overriding-oncreateinputconnection) post is able to at least force change the Done button text. Never tried it though. I know, for your first question, that the different version of Android will be drastically different in terms of how they handle input types and/or if they support them at all. It is extremely unfortunately. What is the lowest Android version you are targeting?

Comment: Lowest is 4.2.2 for now. I will read through the post you mention and see what I come up with.  I think extending the Webview is the way forward, just want to know which part of it I need to set to force a particular soft keyboard, or which parts of the web site I need to have modified

Comment: @hvaughan3 - that post helped a lot, we have managed to find an acceptable compromise for now. Assigning

    outAttrs.ImeOptions = (ImeFlags)ImeAction.Next;

However, I was hoping to just dismiss the keyboard as the device soft button does. Can't see an option in the enum. Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: The issue is that `ImeAction.Next` is used to [take the user to the next input](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_NEXT) and not for dismissing the keyboard. I wonder if you could listen for the Next button being pressed and manually dismiss the keyboard yourself though... Might be worth a shot. If you need code to manually dismiss the keyboard let me know, though I have never tried to use the dismiss code against a keyboard launch via a `WebView`

Comment: @hvaughan3 - yes, code to manually dismiss keyboard would be very useful.  Although listening for the next button being pressed would be the same as trapping the keydown event I assume? Or did you have another way to trap the event in mind?

Comment: Right, you would need to trap the key presses either in JavaScript code or in C# code for that unfortunately. Maybe you could inject JavaScript into the WebView on your `<input>` which looks for the enter key to be pressed and removes focus..? Not sure if that would dismiss the keyboard or not and that it also sort of a hack. Does adding `ImeFlags.NoEnterAction` make any difference to if the keyboard gets dismissed?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Yes, I was trying to avoid injecting our own scripts. Would like the third party to find the problem and fix at source instead of us hacking around but we have a release due and a quick + dirty solution is all we have available to us at this time.  The NoEnterAction selection seems to re-submit the page and not just dismiss. Thanks for your input, think we are stuck with next for now

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help out a bit. I will post my first comment as at least part of the answer for others. Hopefully someone else will come along and give a better more complete one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments: To your second question about forcing a keyboard button, you can check out [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65222/inputmethods-editorinfo-imeoptions-data-type-wrong-problem-when-overriding-oncreateinputconnection) which describes how to override `OnCreateInputConnection` to specify the Keyboard Enter Button type.

```
public class MyWebView : WebView {
    ...
    public override IInputConnection OnCreateInputConnection (EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        var inputConnection = base.OnCreateInputConnection (outAttrs);
        // outAttrs.ImeOptions in Xamarin only allows ImeFlags but it also should allow ImeActions
        outAttrs.ImeOptions = outAttrs.ImeOptions | (ImeFlags)ImeAction.Next;
        return inputConnection;
    }
}
```

That will not dismiss your keyboard when tapped though since it is meant to [take the user to the next input](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_NEXT). Hopefully someone else can come along and either provide a better answer or give a good way to dismiss the keyboard in this situation without hacking something together.